# Laravel relationships (one to many)

Tags: laravel, table-relationships

I am new to Laravel and maybe somebody can give me an example for this.
I have two tables - `Auhors` and `Books` and two views - `authors.index` and `books.index`.
I know how to display all the books related to author in authors.index, but the question is, **how to display all authors related books in `books.index` view?**
My models and BookController:

[Authors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nq4iE.png)

[Books](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWTQX.png)

[BooksController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rwTx.png)

Comment: Provide your code directly here, not an link to an image of ... code, please. We can't use image as a code

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the opposite function `belongsTo` into your `Books` model.

```
public function authors() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Authors::class, 'author_id', 'id');
}
```

You can find more info [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-belongs-to-relationships)

Comment: well. The answer is correct. The problem should solve.

Comment: Thank you for answer! But what should I write in my BooksController index function, to display all authors related books in books.index view?